# Is it possible to enable WebAudio processing for Cross-Origin Resources with appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I am building an audio application that have two servers involved. Server A is dedicated for audio streaming, while B servers a HTML page that loads audio sources from A.

The audios are OK to play. However, when I try to do some magic with WebAudio API, I got message saying

> "MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access
>   restrictions for {{URL of audio src}}"

This is fair because [WebAudio spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) said

> HTMLMediaElement allows the playback of cross-origin resources.
>   Because Web Audio allows inspection of the content of the resource
>   (e.g. using a MediaElementAudioSourceNode, and a ScriptProcessorNode
>   to read the samples), information leakage can occur if scripts from
>   one origin inspect the content of a resource from another origin.
>
> To prevent this, a MediaElementAudioSourceNode MUST output silence
>   instead of the normal output of the HTMLMediaElement if it has been
>   created using an HTMLMediaElement for which the execution of the fetch
>   algorithm labeled the resource as CORS-cross-origin.

The question is **what if I do want to have this "Cross-origin" inspection**?

I have full control on the outputs of both servers, so I came up with two ideas.

1. Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers. This is what worked for
   CORS `XMLHttpRequest`. However, it does not work for WebAudio API. Do
   I need some other headers?
2. Do some trick on domain mapping or headers, to let browser think A
   and B are (logically) the same domain. So far I have no idea if it
   is actually feasible.

Should I have more options? Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Note:**

Proxying with server B is not an option for me, because the purpose of A is to offload such work from B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer by myself.

The solution is to add `crossOrigin="anonymous"` attribute to corresponding audio element.