# The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I was testing changing audio gain of a video. I created a sample HTML page, and the video file is on the same directory as the HTML file. There was no web server; I just created the file on my local disk and opened it with FireFox. The code is below, but when I clicked the button I got

> The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a
>   cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.

and the audio got muted. How can I fix this? I searched here and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906591/is-it-possible-to-enable-webaudio-processing-for-cross-origin-resources-with-app), and the answer was "The solution is to add crossOrigin="anonymous" attribute to corresponding audio element." but that did not seem to work.

```
   <script crossOrigin="anonymous">
        function gain(value)
        {
            var vid = document.getElementById("testvideo");

            var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
            var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
            gainNode.gain.value = value;

            var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(vid);
            ...
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="testvideo" width="640", height="360" controls>
        <source src="sample.webm" type="video/mp4" crossOrigin="anonymous"/>
    </video>    

    <div>
        <button onclick="gain(2)">Gain 2</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I remember well, for me this fixed when I used a live server on my visual studio code.

Answer (score 7):

not sure if this fixes you but :

here :

[Firefox WebAudio createMediaElementSource not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180550/firefox-webaudio-createmediaelementsource-not-working)

i had the same error , i put crossorigin in the audio tag and it seems to work :

```
<div class= fph id=fph align=center>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<audio crossorigin="anonymous" src="<?php
$toevallegnummer = rand(1,3);
    if ($toevallegnummer == 1){echo "https://res.cloudinary.com/ddxo40bkm/video/upload/v1582653810/alleycat/shorty.ogg";}
    if ($toevallegnummer == 2){echo "https://res.cloudinary.com/ddxo40bkm/video/upload/v1582653811/alleycat/raveretro.ogg";}
    if ($toevallegnummer == 3){echo "https://res.cloudinary.com/ddxo40bkm/video/upload/v1582653811/alleycat/raveretrorevisedloop.ogg";}
?>" id="audio" >audio element not supported</audio>
<script src="dir/dir/somthing.js"></script>
</div>
```

im not really a pro or anything but maybe this helps , if not you , then mayb someone else